# Syslog-ng 2.0.9 documentation

Tags: syslog-ng

I am looking for some documentation on syslog-ng version 2.0.9. I have to tweak on an old SUSE 11.2 installation. Official syslog-ng has only documentation starting from 3.5 version. Anyone may share a link to access documentation for older versions ?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be in the syslog-ng source tree, its last revision from roughly that time is here https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/blob/1bffb002ab3ef4b9854e1379cd9dc329523059df/doc/reference/syslog-ng.xml

It is a docbook format which you can convert to HTML using:

```
xsltproc --nonet --path ./doc -o ./doc/reference/syslog-ng.html/index.html  \
    ./doc/reference/syslog-ng.xsl   \
    ./doc/reference/syslog-ng.xml
```

If you download the source tree for that version, the documentation is in its doc/reference folder.